# What should be the image/bitmap size in Android BigPictureStyle push notification?

Tags: android, bitmap, push-notification, notifications, android-notifications

I want some clarity on image size of BigPictureStyle bitmap in notification.

I have gone through some tutorials but could not find the size specifications about this bitmap.

Some told to have 2:1 aspect ratio.

I want some clarity like what is recommended size of bitmap/image in

```
 NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle s = new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle().bigPicture(bitmap_image);
        s.setSummaryText("Summary text appears on expanding the notification");
         notificationBuilder.setStyle(s);
```

please guide me through this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can find a Google I/O slideshow presentation [here](http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/io2012/presentations/live%20to%20website/105.pdf) that mentions this (presentation by Chet Haase, Romain Guy & Dan Sandler).

Specifically on slide 52 it states about BigPictureStyle:

> **Protips**
>
> Images should be ≤ 450dp wide, ~2:1 aspect
> Bitmaps outside these bounds will just be wasting
> RAM (and possibly exceeding Binder IPC limits)

Note that this presentation is a couple years old, but there is no reason to deviate from its suggestions.

Related: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=36744

Answer (score 1):

it should be an .png image with transparent background .* 710*90* its an image size i am using and its working well . :)